# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named <package>" in my Docker container

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to run a python script in a Docker container, and i don't know why, python can't find any of the python's module. I thaught it has something to do with the PYTHONPATH env variable, so i tried to add it in the Dockerfile like this : `ENV PYTHONPATH $PYTHONPATH`

But it didn't work.
this is what my Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
MAINTAINER SaveMe SaveMe@Desperate.com

ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y locales

# Set the locale
RUN sed -i -e 's/# en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/' 
/etc/locale.gen && \
    locale-gen
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
ENV PYTHONPATH ./app

#Install dependencies
RUN echo "===> Installing sudo to emulate normal OS behavior..."
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN apt-add-repository universe
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6
RUN (apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y -q && apt-get dist-upgrade -
y -q && apt-get -y -q autoclean && apt-get -y -q autoremove)
RUN apt-get install -y libxml2-dev libxslt-dev
RUN apt-get install -y python3.6 python3.6-dev python3.6-venv openssl 
ca-certificates python3-pip
RUN apt-get install -y  python3-dev python-dev libffi-dev gfortran
RUN apt-get install -y swig
RUN apt-get install -y sshpass openssh-client rsync python-pip python-
dev libffi-dev libssl-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libjpeg8-dev 
zlib1g-dev libpulse-dev
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install bugsnag

#Install python package + requirements.txt
RUN  pip3 install  -r requirements.txt


CMD ["python3.6", "import_emails.py"]
```

when i'm trying to run: `sudo docker run <my_container>` i got this Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "import_emails.py", line 9, in <module>
    import bugsnag
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bugsnag'
```

As you can see i'm using python3.6 for this project. Any lead on how to solve this ?

Comment: I answered below, but I wanted to give you a recommendation to [minimize your layers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#minimize-the-number-of-layers) by combining RUN calls. Depending on your Docker version it might not matter much, but if you expect others to use your images I believe at this point it's considered not just functionally beneficial but also proper formatting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside the container, when I `pip install bugsnag`, I get the following:

```
root@af08af24a458:/app# pip install bugsnag
Requirement already satisfied: bugsnag in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied: webob in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from bugsnag)
Requirement already satisfied: six<2,>=1.9 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from bugsnag)
```

You probably see the problem here. You're installing the package for python2.7, which is the OS default, instead of python3.6, which is what you're trying to use.

Check out this answer for help resolving this issue: ["ModuleNotFoundError: No module named <package>" in my Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47355844/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-package-in-my-docker-container)

Alternatively, this is a problem `virtualenv` and similar tools are meant to solve, you could look into that as well.

Comment: Thanks, actually i needed to add both `RUN  python3.6 -m pip install --upgrade pip` and `RUN  python3.6 -m pip install -r requirements.txt` (bugsnag was in my requirements file). but now, when i add my directory to `/app` it ignoring some files and directory i don't know why. any idea ?

Comment: @RayaneBouslimi hard to say without seeing your file structure. if you are mounting volumes in your `docker run` inside of `/app`, you might be inadvertently mounting over files/directories you expect to be there from the `ADD` command in the build. Have you `docker exec`'d into your container to look around?

Comment: My bad, problem solved, my coworker has change the `.dockerignore`, that's why i was missing some env variable ! thank you for your time

Comment: Why does this answer links to this question?

Comment: that was it! the mounted volume was doing something

Answer (score 1):

since you're using py3, try using pip3 to install bugsnag instead of pip

Comment: stepping into that trap every time I use an image with pyhton2 installed.