# Docker image and ENV command for PYTHONPATH: module not found even when locally runs fine

Tags: python, docker, pythonpath

I've got a Python job that I'm trying to ship in a Docker image. The code is structured in such a way that some modules get imported from a `modules` folder, so I've added to the Python path.

Specifically, the Dockerfile is

```
FROM python:3

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app

ENV PYTHONPATH "/usr/src/app"

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

As you can see, I'm trying to set the environment variable for PYTHONPATH so it would find stuff in the same working directory.

The script to run is called `main.py` and when I run it locally (not from docker) as

```
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$HOME/job-path python3 main.py
```

it runs fine.

With that Dockerfile instesd, after building the image I get, from a `docker inspect <ID>`, that the Env field contains

```
"Env": [
            "PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "LANG=C.UTF-8",
            "PYTHON_VERSION=3.6.4",
            "PYTHON_PIP_VERSION=9.0.1",
            "PYTHONPATH=/usr/src/app"
        ]
```

so it'd look like it's fine? But `docker run` gives me a

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modules'
```

Comment: Can you append your docker run command with `-e PYTHONPATH="/usr/src/app"` and try running it again?

Comment: @SagarRuchandani Done, doesn't work either, same outcome.

Comment: Not sure what's going on inside the container. Can this be a possible duplicate of  
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47355844/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-package-in-my-docker-container

Comment: You realize that in setting the ENV in the dockerfile you exchanged it instead of appending it right? I advise to do: `ENV PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/usr/src/app"` instead

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: @SebastianFleck It's probably not set to anything else before this...?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is

```
ENV variable1[=value1] variable2[=value2] ...
```

Without an equals sign, you are creating two empty variables; the name of the second is `/usr/src/app`.  You want

```
ENV PYTHONPATH="/usr/src/app"
```

with an equals sign between the variable's name and its value.

If you want to append to an existing value, you can:

```
ENV PYTHONPATH="/usr/src/app:${PYTHONPATH}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue here that probably you do not have `__init__.py` in your src folder that you copy to `/usr/src/app`. That is why `modules` package wasn't recognized. You either can add `__init__.py` to your src folder or add `modules` to PYTHONPATH

```
ENV PYTHONPATH "/usr/src/app/:/usr/src/app/modules/"
```

Note that if your `modules` folder has subfolders it should also contain `__init__.py`